# Get my data from database in hashmap

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap

I am trying to get data in hashmap from database. I am not getting data properly as the original query returns.

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
{

        q.append("SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(updatedOn) as updatedOnDate FROM t_user_segment WHERE updatedOn >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 15 DAY) group by updatedOnDate;");
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(q.toString());
        List<Object[]> result = query.list();
        for (Object[] object : result)
        {
            System.out.println(hm.put(object[0].toString(),object[1].toString()));
            //hm.put(object[0].toString(), object[1].toString());
        }
    }
```

I am getting data like this:

```
null
null
null
2015-10-27
null
2015-10-26
2015-10-30
2015-11-05
```

But when I run the same query on SQL I get original data like this:

```
3 2015-10-27
4 2015-10-27
4 2015-10-27
5 2015-10-27
3 2015-10-27
2 2015-10-26
5 2015-10-30
3 2015-11-05
```

So please someone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: *I am getting data like this:*, where are getting those data? What and where are you doing that print?

Comment: i am getting on eclipse console

Comment: Where are the output coming from your code? I mean you should have `System.out.println` or something like that in your code. Please post that part

Comment: System.out.println is already in code in dise for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `System.out` on `HashMap.put`.

If you read the JavaDoc for [HashMap.put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) it says:

> **Returns**:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

So your code is printing `null` when the value is first *put* because there's no previous *value* for the given *key*, then the second *put* returns the previous *value*.

Basically, given a result set in this order, you'll get:

```
3 2015-10-27 //no value for key 3, prints null
4 2015-10-27 //no value for key 4, prints null
4 2015-10-27 //value exists for key 4, prints previous value - 2015-10-27
5 2015-10-27 //no value for key 5, prints null
3 2015-10-27 //value exists for key 3, prints previous value - 2015-10-27
2 2015-10-26 //no value for key 2, prints null
5 2015-10-30 //value exists for key 5, prints previous value - 2015-10-27
3 2015-11-05 //value exists for key 3, prints previous value - 2015-10-27
```

Using a `System.out` is not a very good way to debug, you should inspect the variables in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) the `put` method

> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

This explains the output you are getting. So as you have duplicate entries for example 3 (`3 2015-10-27`) you are once getting `null` and then getting the previous value `2015-10-27`. As there are 4 duplicate entries you are getting 4 printouts and others are `null`

Now `HashMap` cannot have multiple entries for a single key, So if you really want to store duplicate entries `HashMap` is not for you.

To fix the output, do not print the result of `put` method. You can complete populating the `HashMap` and then print it. Like change

```
    for (Object[] object : result)
    {
        System.out.println(hm.put(object[0].toString(),object[1].toString()));
        //hm.put(object[0].toString(), object[1].toString());
    }
```

to

```
    for (Object[] object : result)
    {
        hm.put(object[0].toString(),object[1].toString()));
        //hm.put(object[0].toString(), object[1].toString());
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hm) {
        System.out.println(entry.key + " " + entry.value);
    }
```